# Webassets - exclude file in bundle

Tags: python, web-applications, webassets

I have a directory and want to exclude a few files like Ant does, is this possible with webassets?

Or does if bundle could take a list or tuple, which doesn't seem to be the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Bundle` constructor signature looks like this (from [the source at github](https://github.com/miracle2k/webassets/blob/master/src/webassets/bundle.py#L48)):

```
def __init__(self, *contents, **options):
```

That means that the contents can be specified as a series of positional arguments, as in [the example in the documentation](http://elsdoerfer.name/files/docs/webassets/bundles.html#bundles):

```
Bundle('common/inheritance.js', 'portal/js/common.js',
   'portal/js/plot.js', 'portal/js/ticker.js',
   filters='jsmin',
   output='gen/packed.js')
```

But it also means that you can use Python's ability [unpack argument lists](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists). From that page:

> The reverse situation occurs when the arguments are already in a list or tuple but need to be unpacked for a function call requiring separate positional arguments. For instance, the built-in range() function expects separate start and stop arguments. If they are not available separately, write the function call with the *-operator to unpack the arguments out of a list or tuple

So you could just easily the write the example above as:

```
files = ['common/inheritance.js', 'portal/js/common.js', 
         'portal/js/plot.js', 'portal/js/ticker.js']
Bundle(*files, filters='jsmin', output='gen/packed.js')
```

and of course you can filter/slice/dice the list to your hearts content before bundling.

Comment: Also I found with mixing the data types in Bundle args you have to have your list as the last non-named input.

    Bundle('dir/**/*.js','otherdir/*.js', *files, filters='jsmin',     
    output='gen/main.min.js')

Thanks again for your help.